# Jquery value keeps updating to the latest clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table that reveals a subtable. Within that subtable, it will calculate the amount of users via ajax and jquery. However, when i click to expand another subtable, the values update to the one just clicked instead of retaining their values. How do i solve this? The classes are totalagents and totalusers. Each subtable is supposed to have their own count.

Jquery

```
$('.expandlink_admin').on('click', function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var curr_row = $row.data('id');
    var company = $(this).closest('td').data('company');
    var privilege = $(this).closest('td').data('privilege');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/manager/administrator/users/count_agents_users',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            id: curr_row,
            company: company,
            privilege: privilege
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $(".subtable").each(function() { //loop through each row
                if ($("[type='hidden']", this).val() == curr_row) {
                    $(this).show();
                    $row.find('.expandlink_admin').hide();
                    $row.find('.shrinklink_admin').show();
                    $('.totalagents').html(result.agents);
                    $('.totalusers').html(result.users);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<tbody>
    <?php $offset = $this->uri->segment(5,0)+1; ?>
        <?php foreach($user as $row): ?>
            <tr data-id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
                <td>
                    <?php echo $offset++; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row->company; ?>
                </td>
                <td data-company="<?php echo $row->company; ?>" data-privilege="<?php echo $row->privilege; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" />
                    <input type="button" class="expandlink_admin" value="+" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" />
                    <input type="button" class="shrinklink_admin" value="-" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="company" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="set" value="edit" />
                    <input type="button" class="editlink_company" value="Edit" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="company" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="set" value="delete" />
                    <input type="button" class="deletelink" value="Delete" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="subtable">
                <td colspan="9">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" />
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Total Agents : </td>
                            <td class="totalagents"></td>
                            <td>Address : </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $row->address; ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Total Users : </td>
                            <td class="totalusers"></td>
                            <td>Date Added : </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $row->date_added; ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Expected result

```
Row 1
<br/>Total Agents : 4
<br/>Total Users : 2
<br/>Row 2
<br/>Total Agents : 2
<br/>Total Users : 12
<br/>
```

Actual result

```
Row 1
<br/>Total Agents : 4
<br/>Total Users : 2
<br/>Row 2
<br/>Total Agents : 4
<br/>Total Users : 2
```

Comment: values update means?? Updates in Table?

Comment: Yeah. the totalagents and totalusers for each row update to the latest clicked instead of retaining their values. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Sorry did you mean the class names?

Comment: I would suggest providing output HTML next time and not source PHP. I hate mentally compiling PHP. It gives me a headache :)

Comment: That result shown could be purely down to the return values from the server being incorrect. Have deleted answer for now until we understand the question better :)

Comment: When the server returns a value for total agent and total user, it overrides the previous row as well.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in case anyone was wondering

```
$(".subtable").each(function() { //loop through each row
            if($("[type='hidden']", this).val() == curr_row) { 
            //$(this) means subtable
                 $(this).show();
                 $row.find('.expandlink_admin').hide();
                 $row.find('.shrinklink_admin').show();
                 $(this).find('.totalagents').html(result.agents);
                 $(this).find('.totalusers').html(result.users);
             }
     });
```